# Is there such a thing as a free quasivariety?

Tags: universal-algebra

I have heard in universal algebra there is such a thing as a free variety, but is there such a thing as a free quasivariety? I would assume, that, for instance, in the language of a single binary operation symbol $*$, a free quasivariety is a free variety where additionally if $x*y=z*w$, then $x=z$ and $y=w$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no such concepts as "free variety" or "free quasi-variety" in Universal Algebra. There are free objects in a variety (quasi-variety).

Comment: What is a free object in a quasi-variety?

Comment: The same definition as for variety.

Comment: The thing is that if $\cal C$ is a set of algebras then the free algebras in the variety $var(\cal C)$ are in $qvar(\cal C)$.